# Can we use LIKE operator along with MEMBER OF operator in a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, memberof

I have an array of data using which I select rows from a table. For that I use member of operator in where clause. I want to know if we can do that same but by using Like operator along with member of operator.

When my Array consists of{Delhi, Mumbai, Kolkata}
I select the rows which have these three values in their row. 
This is how I do that:

```
select ...
Into...
From xyz where city member of array;
///Receiving the array from an in parameter of the stored procedure.
```

And it works perfectly fine.
But If `my array has {Del, Mum, Kolk} //parts of the actual names`
How do I use this array for the same purpose, maybe using Like operator.

```
Create or replace zz2(ar in array_collection, c out sys_refcursor)
Is
anotherabc tablename.city%type
Begin
Open c
For
Select ABC
Into anotherabc
From tablename where city member of ar;
End zz2;
```

I expect the output to have all the rows which have cities starting with the alphabet/characters present in the array. Using member of operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
Select ABC
Into anotherabc a
From tablename WHERE EXISTS 
  ( select 1 FROM ( select column_value as city  
     FROM TABLE(ar) ) s where a.city like s.city||'%' )
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to use `LIKE` with `MEMBER OF`.

If It is the protocol that your collection contains the first three characters of the city name then you can use `substr()` to match only the first three characters in `MEMBER OF`.

try the following thing:

```
DECLARE
  TYPE t_tab IS TABLE OF varchar(3);
  l_tab1 t_tab := t_tab('Del','Mom','Kol');
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put('Is ''Delhi'' MEMBER OF l_tab1? ');
  IF SUBSTR('Delhi',1,3) MEMBER OF l_tab1 THEN -- note the use of SUBSTR here
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('TRUE');
  ELSE
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('FALSE');  
  END IF;
END;
/
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0d08a284b86ce8bdeb7cbd34166f52a4)

Cheers!!